# Can this drug make "zombies" out of people in the sense they will do whatever they are told?

Tags: hypnotism, medications

From [here](http://topdocumentaryfilms.com/worlds-scariest-drug/) the drug referred to as Devil's breath "renders a person incapable of exercising free will". In the video at 3:27 one person claims people under the influence are completely susceptible to suggestion and would do things like write a person a check if told to do so. To what extent are these statements true? I found the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scopolamine) article on this and it mentions nothing about "free will" or "mind control".